# Оптимизация поиска одинаковых комбинаций в массивах

Tags: php, массивы, комбинаторика

Есть массивы из чисел от 1 до 64, в которых нужно найти одинаковые комбинации, допустим из 7 чисел. Делаю тупо перебором чисел через цикл for, на что соответственно получаю примерно часовое выполнение скрипта. Хотелось бы побыстрее, если возможно. Заранее благодарю.

массивы:

```
$arr[0] = 05 12 14 20 21 22 23 26 30 31 32 34 41 45 48 49 52 53 54 63;
$arr[1] = 02 03 06 12 13 17 30 32 40 41 44 46 48 50 52 53 55 57 58 61;
$arr[2] = 01 06 07 08 12 13 16 20 23 24 31 33 34 36 37 43 50 53 58 61;
$arr[3] = 05 06 08 15 16 23 25 26 28 32 33 34 43 45 49 51 55 58 61 62;
$arr[4] = 01 08 10 12 23 28 31 33 35 36 38 40 42 45 46 48 49 56 62 63;

2 одинаковые комбинации из 7 чисел в $arr[2] и $arr[4] = 01 08 12 23 31 33 36;
```

перебор комбинаций из 7 чисел от 1 до 64 :

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 64; $i++) {
        
    for ($b = ($i+1); $b <= 64; $b++) {
            
        for ($c = ($b+1); $c <= 64; $c++) {
                
            for ($d = ($c+1); $d <= 64; $d++) {
                    
                for ($f = ($d+1); $f <= 64; $f++) {
                        
                    for ($e = ($f+1); $e <= 64; $e++) {
                        
                        for ($g = ($e+1); $g <= 64; $g++) {
```

непосредственно сам поиск:

```
for ($row = 0; $row <= 4; $row++) {

if (in_array($i, $arr[$row]) and in_array($b, $arr[$row]) and in_array($c, $arr[$row]) and in_array($d, $arr[$row]) and in_array($f, $arr[$row]) and in_array($e, $arr[$row]) and in_array($g, $arr[$row])){ ... }
```

вывод:

```
2 --    1, 8, 12, 23, 31, 33, 36    4 --    1, 8, 12, 23, 31, 33, 36    
0 --    5, 23, 26, 32, 34, 45, 49   3 --    5, 23, 26, 32, 34, 45, 49   
2 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 33, 34, 43    3 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 33, 34, 43    
2 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 33, 34, 58    3 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 33, 34, 58    
2 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 33, 34, 61    3 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 33, 34, 61    
2 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 33, 43, 58    3 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 33, 43, 58    
2 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 33, 43, 61    3 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 33, 43, 61    
2 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 33, 58, 61    3 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 33, 58, 61    
2 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 34, 43, 58    3 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 34, 43, 58    
2 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 34, 43, 61    3 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 34, 43, 61    
2 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 34, 58, 61    3 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 34, 58, 61    
2 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 43, 58, 61    3 --    6, 8, 16, 23, 43, 58, 61    
2 --    6, 8, 16, 33, 34, 43, 58    3 --    6, 8, 16, 33, 34, 43, 58    
2 --    6, 8, 16, 33, 34, 43, 61    3 --    6, 8, 16, 33, 34, 43, 61    
2 --    6, 8, 16, 33, 34, 58, 61    3 --    6, 8, 16, 33, 34, 58, 61    
2 --    6, 8, 16, 33, 43, 58, 61    3 --    6, 8, 16, 33, 43, 58, 61    
2 --    6, 8, 16, 34, 43, 58, 61    3 --    6, 8, 16, 34, 43, 58, 61    
2 --    6, 8, 23, 33, 34, 43, 58    3 --    6, 8, 23, 33, 34, 43, 58    
2 --    6, 8, 23, 33, 34, 43, 61    3 --    6, 8, 23, 33, 34, 43, 61    
2 --    6, 8, 23, 33, 34, 58, 61    3 --    6, 8, 23, 33, 34, 58, 61    
2 --    6, 8, 23, 33, 43, 58, 61    3 --    6, 8, 23, 33, 43, 58, 61    
2 --    6, 8, 23, 34, 43, 58, 61    3 --    6, 8, 23, 34, 43, 58, 61    
2 --    6, 8, 33, 34, 43, 58, 61    3 --    6, 8, 33, 34, 43, 58, 61    
1 --    6, 12, 13, 50, 53, 58, 61   2 --    6, 12, 13, 50, 53, 58, 61   
2 --    6, 16, 23, 33, 34, 43, 58   3 --    6, 16, 23, 33, 34, 43, 58   
2 --    6, 16, 23, 33, 34, 43, 61   3 --    6, 16, 23, 33, 34, 43, 61   
2 --    6, 16, 23, 33, 34, 58, 61   3 --    6, 16, 23, 33, 34, 58, 61   
2 --    6, 16, 23, 33, 43, 58, 61   3 --    6, 16, 23, 33, 43, 58, 61   
2 --    6, 16, 23, 34, 43, 58, 61   3 --    6, 16, 23, 34, 43, 58, 61   
2 --    6, 16, 33, 34, 43, 58, 61   3 --    6, 16, 33, 34, 43, 58, 61   
2 --    6, 23, 33, 34, 43, 58, 61   3 --    6, 23, 33, 34, 43, 58, 61   
2 --    8, 16, 23, 33, 34, 43, 58   3 --    8, 16, 23, 33, 34, 43, 58   
2 --    8, 16, 23, 33, 34, 43, 61   3 --    8, 16, 23, 33, 34, 43, 61   
2 --    8, 16, 23, 33, 34, 58, 61   3 --    8, 16, 23, 33, 34, 58, 61   
2 --    8, 16, 23, 33, 43, 58, 61   3 --    8, 16, 23, 33, 43, 58, 61   
2 --    8, 16, 23, 34, 43, 58, 61   3 --    8, 16, 23, 34, 43, 58, 61   
2 --    8, 16, 33, 34, 43, 58, 61   3 --    8, 16, 33, 34, 43, 58, 61   
3 --    8, 23, 28, 33, 45, 49, 62   4 --    8, 23, 28, 33, 45, 49, 62   
2 --    8, 23, 33, 34, 43, 58, 61   3 --    8, 23, 33, 34, 43, 58, 61   
0 --    12, 23, 31, 45, 48, 49, 63  4 --    12, 23, 31, 45, 48, 49, 63  
0 --    12, 30, 32, 41, 48, 52, 53  1 --    12, 30, 32, 41, 48, 52, 53  
2 --    16, 23, 33, 34, 43, 58, 61  3 --    16, 23, 33, 34, 43, 58, 61
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже ваша задача предполагает поиск пересечений в двух массивах. Вот пример реализации на php 7.4. Поскольку результат пересечений двух массивов может дать результат длинной больше необходимого, в вашем слачае 7, то необходимо найти все подмассивы пересечения.

```
$arr = [
    [5, 12, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 26, 30, 31, 32, 34, 41, 45, 48, 49, 52, 53, 54, 63],
    [2, 3, 6, 12, 13, 17, 30, 32, 40, 41, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 53, 55, 57, 58, 61],
    [1, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 16, 20, 23, 24, 31, 33, 34, 36, 37, 43, 50, 53, 58, 61],
    [5, 6, 8, 15, 16, 23, 25, 26, 28, 32, 33, 34, 43, 45, 49, 51, 55, 58, 61, 62],
    [1, 8, 10, 12, 23, 28, 31, 33, 35, 36, 38, 40, 42, 45, 46, 48, 49, 56, 62, 63]
];

function all_combinations($arr, $size) {
    $count = count($arr); 
    $members = pow(2,$count); 
    $return = array(); 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $members; $i++) { 
        $b = sprintf("%0".$count."b", $i); 
        $out = array(); 
        for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) { 
            if ($b[$j] == "1") array_push($out, $arr[$j]); 
        } 
        if (count($out) == $size) { 
            array_push($return, $out); 
        } 
   } 
   return $return; 
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr) - 1; $i++)
    for($j = $i + 1; $j < count($arr); $j++) {
        $res = array_values(array_uintersect($arr[$i], $arr[$j], "strcasecmp"));
        if (count($res) >= 7) {
            $r = all_combinations($res, 7);
            foreach ($r as $c) {
                echo "Пересечение arr[{$i}] и arr[{$j}] = ";
                for ($k = 0; $k < count($c); $k++)
                    echo $c[$k]." "; 
                echo "\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

Вывод:

```
Пересечение arr[0] и arr[1] = 12 30 32 41 48 52 53 
Пересечение arr[0] и arr[3] = 5 23 26 32 34 45 49 
Пересечение arr[0] и arr[4] = 12 23 31 45 48 49 63 
Пересечение arr[1] и arr[2] = 6 12 13 50 53 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 16 23 33 34 43 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 8 23 33 34 43 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 8 16 33 34 43 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 8 16 23 34 43 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 8 16 23 33 43 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 8 16 23 33 34 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 8 16 23 33 34 43 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 8 16 23 33 34 43 58 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 23 33 34 43 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 16 33 34 43 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 16 23 34 43 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 16 23 33 43 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 16 23 33 34 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 16 23 33 34 43 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 16 23 33 34 43 58 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 33 34 43 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 23 34 43 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 23 33 43 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 23 33 34 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 23 33 34 43 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 23 33 34 43 58 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 16 34 43 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 16 33 43 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 16 33 34 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 16 33 34 43 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 16 33 34 43 58 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 16 23 43 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 16 23 34 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 16 23 34 43 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 16 23 34 43 58 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 16 23 33 58 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 16 23 33 43 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 16 23 33 43 58 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 16 23 33 34 61 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 16 23 33 34 58 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[3] = 6 8 16 23 33 34 43 
Пересечение arr[2] и arr[4] = 1 8 12 23 31 33 36 
Пересечение arr[3] и arr[4] = 8 23 28 33 45 49 62
```

Comment: Плюсик вам в карму! Это то что было нужно!

Comment: Однако на практике ваш алгоритм выдает 3 совпадения для комбинаций из 7 чисел массива выше, а мой выдает 42 совпадения для комбинации из 7 чисел. Где-то промашка вышла.

Comment: Для этого же набора данных (arr)?

Comment: именно для этого набора!

Comment: Выше под заданием добавил вывод

Comment: Исправил ответ, попробуйте использовать для вашей задачи

Comment: Это реально круто! Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Как-то у Вас очень сложно написано.

01 заменил на числа 1 и т.д. соответственно.

Попробуйте так как ниже.
На выходе функции массив с массивами в которых есть данная комбинация.

```
$arr = [
    [5, 12, 14, 20, 21, 22,
     23, 26, 30, 31, 32, 34, 41, 45, 48, 49, 52, 53, 54, 63],
    [2, 3, 6, 12, 13, 17, 30, 32, 40, 41, 44,
     46, 48, 50, 52, 53, 55, 57, 58, 61],
    [1, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 16, 20, 22, 24, 31, 33, 34, 36, 37,
     43, 50, 53, 58, 61],
    [5, 6, 8, 15, 16, 23, 25, 26, 28, 32,
     33, 34, 43, 45, 49, 51, 55, 58, 61, 62],
    [1, 8, 10, 15, 23, 28, 31, 33, 35, 36,
     38, 40, 42, 45, 46, 48, 49, 56, 62, 63]
];

function checkArray(array $combination, array $arr):array {
    return array_filter($arr, function($item) use ($combination) {
        $isEvery = false;
        foreach ($combination as $value) {
            $isEvery = in_array($value, $item);
        }
        return $isEvery;
    });
}
echo count(checkArray([1, 8, 12, 23, 31, 33, 36], $arr));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Может я не совсем точно объяснил, но имелось  в виду что комбинация из 7 чисел это неизвестное, которое повторяется больше одного раза в массивах. Как раз ее и надо  каким то образом вычислить, а не найти в массиве.